# Problema con la propiedad min de ion-datetime Ionic

Tags: ionic, datetime, datetimepicker

Tengo dos pequeños problemas con `ion-datetime`

**Caso 1:**
En el primer caso no se por que razón cuando le doy click me bota el siguiente error

```
<ion-datetime class="ocultar datetime datetime-ios ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" displayformat="DDD DD de MMMM YYYY , hh:mm A" max="2050" ng-reflect-min="18/4/2018 15:21:25" ng-reflect-max="2050" ng-reflect-display-format="DDD DD de MMMM YYYY , hh:mm A" ng-reflect-model="2018-04-25T17:58" id="date1"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}--><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "Wed 25 de Abril 2018 , 17:58 P"
}--><div class="datetime-text">Wed 25 de Abril 2018 , 17:58 PM</div><button aria-haspopup="true" class="item-cover item-cover-ios item-cover-default item-cover-default-ios" ion-button="item-cover" type="button" id="undefined" aria-disabled="false"><span class="button-inner"></span><div class="button-effect"></div></button></ion-datetime>
```

**Error 1**

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'year' of null
>       at DateTime.calcMinMax (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:67400:24)
>       at DateTime.generate (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:67159:18)
>       at DateTime.open (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:67139:14)
>       at DateTime._click (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:67106:14)
>       at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (ng:///AppModule/PedidosPage.ngfactory.js:80:51)
>       at handleEvent (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:13608:172)
>       at callWithDebugContext (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:15093:42)
>       at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:14680:12)
>       at dispatchEvent (http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:10057:25)
>       at http://localhost:8100/build/vendor.js:10671:38

En este caso le pase a la propiedad min el formato que me devuelve `(new Date()).toLocaleString()` ***18/4/2018 10:12:26***

**Caso 2:** En el segundo caso le paso el formato que devuelve  `new Date().toJSON()` ***2018-04-18T15:21:25.380Z*** y cuando le doy click no me bota error, pero cuando me ubico en el día mínimo ***2018-04-18***, las horas se desabilitan y no me permite seleccionar una hora en el componente, la lógica seria que me permitiera seleccionar una hora superior a ***15:21:25.380***

```
<ion-datetime class="ocultar datetime datetime-ios ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" displayformat="DDD DD de MMMM YYYY , hh:mm A" max="2050" ng-reflect-min="2018-04-18T15:21:25.380Z" ng-reflect-max="2050" ng-reflect-display-format="DDD DD de MMMM YYYY , hh:mm A" ng-reflect-model="2018-04-25T17:58" id="date1"><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}--><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "Wed 25 de Abril 2018 , 17:58 P"
}--><div class="datetime-text">Wed 25 de Abril 2018 , 17:58 PM</div><button aria-haspopup="true" class="item-cover item-cover-ios item-cover-default item-cover-default-ios" ion-button="item-cover" type="button" id="undefined" aria-disabled="false"><span class="button-inner"></span><div class="button-effect"></div></button></ion-datetime>
```

Este error solo sucede si uso el  `displayformat="DDD DD de MMMM YYYY , hh:mm A"` pero si uso  `displayformat="DDD DD de MMMM YYYY , HH:mm A"` todo funciona perfectamente, pero no deseo trabajar con el formato de hora 24, ¿Como corrijo cualquiera de los dos casos?

Comment: En este momento paso por algo similar, lograste resolverlo en su momento? si es así, publica tu solución por favor. Saludos! =)